# Paperclip DB storage: Attachments go in, but don't come out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
irb(main):001:0> e = Event.last
=> #<Event id: 7, address: "123 Main St", start_date: "2011-02-09", start_time: "2000-01-01 14:49:00", title: "Test Event", poster_file: "\377���JFIF\000\001\002\000\000d\000d\000\000\377�Ducky\000\001\000\004\000\000\0002\000\000\377�!Adobe\000d�...", poster_thumb_file: nil, created_at: "2011-02-09 14:49:45", updated_at: "2011-02-09 14:49:45", poster_file_name: nil, poster_content_type: "image/jpeg", poster_file_size: 134218, poster_updated_at: "2011-02-09 14:49:44">
irb(main):002:0> e.poster.url
=> "/posters/original/missing.png?1297262984"
```

I am using a fork of the paperclip gem from [Pat Shaughnessy](https://github.com/patshaughnessy/paperclip). I have also tried, and gotten the same problem with another fork found [here](http://github.com/cbrunnkvist/paperclip), so I am pretty sure this is just me doing something stupid. My app is hosted on heroku.
I followed [the instructions](http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/4/14/database-storage-for-paperclip-rewritten-to-use-a-single-table) of the person who originally forked paperclip and tried to adapt them to Rails 3. My route for the poster looks like this:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get :poster
  end
end
```

and in the controller I have:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController       
  downloads_files_for :event, :poster
...
end
```

and the model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :poster_thumb_file, :poster_file_name
  has_attached_file :poster, :storage => :database, :styles => {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100>", :column => 'poster_thumb_file'}}
end
```

I can't figure out what I am missing to get these images to display. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try plural "posters" in your routes file:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get :posters
  end
end
```

The downloads_files_for method assumes the plural attachment name in the URL; see: https://github.com/patshaughnessy/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/database.rb#L190

If you want to use "poster" and not "posters" in the URL then you'll have to write the controller action yourself manually. Basically it's just Event.find... and then call send_data with Event.poster.file_contents and pass the type and filename also.

Did this fix it? - pat

Comment: Thanks for answering Pat. For some reason its still not working. I can see them there in the DB. So close yet so far...

Comment: With the route you suggest I should be able to see the poster at the url /events/posters/8?style=original right? I get: No route matches "/events/posters/8"

Comment: Nope - it would be /events/8/posters?style=original and style would be original by default. You can run "rake routes" and see what the route patterns are...

Comment: Well I am not sure what changed... maybe the extra s... When I go to "/events/8/posters?style=original" it pops up a window to download a jpeg image. Mime issues I guess. e.poster.url still returns "/posters/original/missing.png?1297284160" though. Not there yet, but still progress!

Comment: Hey Mike sorry this is so hard... feel free to pastie/email me enough code to reproduce and I'll take a closer look at it. pat@patshaughnessy.net